# iOS 6, ARC: primitive type instance variable loses value

Tags: ios, int, automatic-ref-counting, instance-variables

I face a simple problem that I don't understand how to solve. Looks like ARC is involved, but where and how I've got no clue. In viewWillAppear I check the value of int fetched from sqlite and assign its value to instance int var.

Setting NSLogs in viewWillAppear indicates that kStatus.grade getting the right value and after assignment of its value to instance var _currentGrade, _currentGrade gets the same int value. The magic happens when viewWillAppear exits. _currentGrade loses its value and getting default 0.

Just curious where's the evil.

```
@property (nonatomic)int currentGrade;


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    DBAccess *acc=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    if(_iCameFromItems==1)
    {
      NSMutableArray *arr=[acc selectItemStatus:_someID];
      kmStatus *kStatus=[arr objectAtIndex:0];
      _currentGrade=kStatus.grade;
      // _currentGrade is that instance var
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. R U sure it is ivar, not a property? 2. U should use `self.property` 3. Check if it is `strong`.

Comment: I was thinking the same as Anoop

Comment: @HalR:Wow same 3 points almost same time :p

Comment: It can't be `strong`, it's not an object.  And it must be either an autogenerated ivar or an explicitly synthesized one, or the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell sure. int is primitive type. Not a pointer.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell: when i posted the answer i guess `@prop` was not there. Or in hurry, i missed that line.

Comment: @Nathan, I think you're going to need to show us more code about how you're determining that the value is a) being set correctly and then b) becoming "unset".  There's nothing obviously wrong here (though I agree that using property setters is generally a better practice than directly setting ivars).

Comment: There's no more code. I tried to synthesize it but the same result.

Comment: @synthesize currentGrade=_currentGrade; tried this as well. viewDidLoad says _currentGrade=0;

Comment: Please show the code where `self.currentGrade` doesn't have a value.

Comment: I archived my goal by moving the code from viewWillAppear to viewDidLoad, but damn I still don't understand WHY the int dies after viewWillAppear?

Comment: Assignment is correct in the code above, so there is two possible cases - currentGrade set to 0 somewere in your code after viewWillAppear, or you use different ViewController (allocate it second time, etc).

Comment: Be aware that viewWillAppear gets called every time the view is shown, whereas viewDidLoad is called once in view controller's lifetime.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - (void)viewDidLoad {[super viewDidLoad]; NSLog(@"%d",_currentGrade); } //output 0; The problem is that int dies after viewWillAppear.

Comment: @dmirkitanov No, No. Before poping up here and showing how stupid I am, I do recheck my code several times.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I call it only once.

Comment: Doesn't viewDidLoad get called after viewWillAppear?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Sure it does. But does it says that viewWillAppear will get called several times?

Comment: @Nathan, viewDidLoad called first, once on object construction. viewWillAppear gets called every time the view appears. Also, there are some situations ([example](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.ru/2012/06/view-will-appear-getting-called-twice.html) ) when you could manually call it twice when porting from older os versions. Try to remove `if` condition, maybe its value changes somehow?

Comment: @dmirkitanov Ok. I will recheck home.